# Why does this JQuery/Ajax form keep failing?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I keep getting the error alert. My php file is right there in the same directory and it functions if I point the browser directly to it.

This is a button that `onCLick` calls `process` and sends `plan_id` as an argument.

```
  <span class="payment_options" id="option2"><button class="btn btn-success" id="paypal_monthly" style="margin-left: 10px;"  onclick="process(this.id);">PayPal</button></span>
```

and this is the script it's calling

```
<script>
function process(plan_id) {
    var data = plan_id;
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process_paypal.php",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) { 
                $.post('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr', data);
                return false;
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("Oh no! An error occured!");
            return false;
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Is there a way I can see more detail about the error? I have chrome's console but its not showing me anything.

Comment: Does the network tab show the Ajax request? What is the status code (200/404)?

Comment: Have you tried logging the data returned to the error function?  `console.log(data)`

Comment: Edit your alert to get more informations about the error: error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(jqXHR + '-' + textStatus + '-' +  errorThrown); return false;}

Comment: I've logged it to console and really don't know what to make of it. What am I looking for exactly among all this gibberish? There is an error `error: function (){if(i){var b=i.length;(function d(b){p.each(b,function(b,c){var e=p.type(c);e==="function"&&...`

Comment: with @gearsdigital error log I got the following `[object Object]-parsererror-SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Answer (score 4):

Send your data as a  key: value pair..

```
var data = { 'plan_id' : plan_id };
```

Comment: I got the following `[object Object]-parsererror-SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` Seen some other posts on this same topic, many of them inconclusive

Answer (score 0):

I narrowed the problem down to the processsing php script. It was calling an HTML/PHP page `header("location: page.php");` and sending it back to the AJAX - hence the character illegal character `<`